# MFC C++ file upload with http post returning invalid win apis

Tags: c++, file-upload, mfc, http-post

I am trying to upload a file using MFC C++ but for some reason i am getting invalid file on the upload. I feels like maybe this is the problem due to wrong header or post information i am using but after several hours tries i cant find my error. Here is my code.. I will appreciate if you experts can elaborate some light on my mistakes so i can correct it...

```
void CFileUpload::UploadByPost(CString strFileName,CString  strServerUrl,CString strServerUploadFile)
{

DWORD dwTotalRequestLength;
DWORD dwChunkLength;
DWORD dwReadLength;
DWORD dwResponseLength;
CHttpFile* pHTTP = NULL;

dwChunkLength = 64 * 1024; 
void* pBuffer = malloc(dwChunkLength);
CFile file ;

if (!file.Open(strFileName.GetBuffer(),
  CFile::modeRead | CFile::shareDenyWrite))
 {
        return;
   }

CInternetSession session(L"sendFile");
CHttpConnection *connection = NULL;

try
{
    //Create the multi-part form data that goes before and after the actual file upload.

    CString strHTTPBoundary = _T("FFF3F395A90B452BB8BEDC878DDBD152");       
    CString strPreFileData = MakePreFileData(strHTTPBoundary, file.GetFileName());
    CString strPostFileData = MakePostFileData(strHTTPBoundary);
    CString strRequestHeaders = MakeRequestHeaders(strHTTPBoundary);
    dwTotalRequestLength = strPreFileData.GetLength() + strPostFileData.GetLength() + file.GetLength();

    connection = session.GetHttpConnection(/*L"www.YOURSITE.com"*/strServerUrl.GetBuffer(),NULL,INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT);

    pHTTP = connection->OpenRequest(CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_POST, strServerUploadFile.GetBuffer());//_T("/YOUURL/submit_file.pl"));
    pHTTP->AddRequestHeaders(strRequestHeaders);
    pHTTP->SendRequestEx(dwTotalRequestLength, HSR_SYNC | HSR_INITIATE);

    //Write out the headers and the form variables
    pHTTP->Write((LPSTR)(LPCSTR)strPreFileData.GetBuffer(), strPreFileData.GetLength());

    //upload the file.

    dwReadLength = -1;
    int length = file.GetLength(); //used to calculate percentage complete.
    while (0 != dwReadLength)
    {
        dwReadLength = file.Read(pBuffer, dwChunkLength);
        if (0 != dwReadLength)
        {
        pHTTP->Write(pBuffer, dwReadLength);
        }
    }

    file.Close();

    //Finish the upload.
    pHTTP->Write((LPSTR)(LPCSTR)strPostFileData.GetBuffer(), strPostFileData.GetLength());
    pHTTP->EndRequest(HSR_SYNC);


    //get the response from the server.
    LPSTR szResponse;
    CString strResponse;
    dwResponseLength = pHTTP->GetLength();
    while (0 != dwResponseLength )
    {
        szResponse = (LPSTR)malloc(dwResponseLength + 1);
        szResponse[dwResponseLength] = '\0';
        pHTTP->Read(szResponse, dwResponseLength);
        strResponse += szResponse;
        free(szResponse);
        dwResponseLength = pHTTP->GetLength();
    }

    TRACE(L"%s",strResponse.GetBuffer());

    //close everything up.
    pHTTP->Close();
    connection->Close();
    session.Close();
}
catch(CInternetException* e)
{
    TRACE(L"error: %d \n",e->m_dwError);
}
catch(CFileException* e)
{
    TRACE(L"error: %d \n",e->m_cause);
}
catch(...)
{
    TRACE(L" unexpected error");
}

}
```

here is my header and post function

```
CString CFileUpload::MakeRequestHeaders(CString& strBoundary)
{
    CString strFormat;
    CString strData;
    strFormat = _T("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=%s\r\n");
    strData.Format(strFormat, strBoundary);
    return strData;
}

CString CFileUpload::MakePreFileData(CString& strBoundary, CString& strFileName)
{
CString strFormat;
CString strData;

strFormat += _T("--%s");
strFormat += _T("\r\n");
strFormat += _T("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"%s\"");
strFormat += _T("\r\n");
strFormat += _T("Content-Type: text/plain");
strFormat += _T("\r\n");
strFormat += _T(" XXXXX ");
strFormat += _T("\r\n\r\n");

strData.Format(strFormat, strBoundary,/* m_Name, strBoundary,*/ strFileName);

return strData;
}

CString CFileUpload::MakePostFileData(CString& strBoundary)
{

    CString strFormat;
CString strData;

strFormat = _T("\r\n");
strFormat += _T("--%s");
strFormat += _T("\r\n");
strFormat += _T("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"submit\"");
strFormat += _T("\r\n\r\n");
strFormat += _T("");
strFormat += _T("\r\n");
strFormat += _T("--%s--");
strFormat += _T("\r\n");

strData.Format(strFormat, strBoundary, strBoundary);

return strData;

}
```

It always return invalid file, the file server code i am using is the following

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("log", "txt");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/plain")
)
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

and here is the form

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Note:- i cant use boost or poco, curl or any third party library.. just only win32 or mfc.

here are the pre make and post make data :

header

```
"Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=FFF3F395A90B452BB8BEDC878DDBD152
"
```

Pre File

```
"--FFF3F395A90B452BB8BEDC878DDBD152
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filename"; filename="ddd.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

"
```

Post File

```
"
--FFF3F395A90B452BB8BEDC878DDBD152
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit" value="submit"


--FFF3F395A90B452BB8BEDC878DDBD152--
"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the error.... this is not because of the post or pre file data or headeror server script but because the way i was calling write function from http object and converting the unicode to ansi without any proper conversion....I dont know how come i didn't realize this silly mistake by me lol...but for the sake of others i would like to share this information as well.....

```
pHTTP->Write((LPSTR)(LPCSTR)strPreFileData.GetBuffer(), strPreFileData.GetLength());
```

must be change to

```
pHTTP->Write((LPSTR)(LPCSTR)CW2A(strPreFileData.GetBuffer()), strPreFileData.GetLength());
```

Also the post file version

```
 pHTTP->Write((LPSTR)(LPCSTR)strPostFileData.GetBuffer(), strPostFileData.GetLength());
```

to

```
 pHTTP->Write((LPSTR)(LPCSTR)CW2A(strPostFileData.GetBuffer()), strPostFileData.GetLength());
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there are three cases in your server-side code that could have gone wrong:

```
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/plain")
)
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
```

Apart from the hideous indentation and brace placement, have you tried testing for each condition separately so that you know what exactly the php parts thinks is wrong?

[mistake has been removed]

Comment: sorry about the indentation and placement... The problem seems not the php server side script because when i do with the form upload then everything works fine. The problem seems like my POST data from my C++ application is not reaching to the server and it always return invalid because in array it finds null including $_POST / $_FILES variable... why its coming null i still couldn't figure out...any more ideas?

Comment: No, the problem is indeed not in your php, the point was that by separating the test condition into three separate ones, you will get to see which of the three fails. From your comment I take it that you know for sure the in_array fails, how do you know? Anyway, can you post the full string of the http request you are sending. I'm not sure which form variables your code is meant to submit. Try to capture the request you get from submitting with an html form (like with firebug) and compare that to the string you are sending through your C++ code.

Comment: sending through forms shows alot of things by firebug so it makes me confuse but here is what i got by debuging it. Check my question's ending editing area...